# Why aren't the unused segment files being deleted?

Tags: azure, lucene.net, lucene

I don't know what changed--things were working relatively well with our Lucene implementation. But now, the number of files in the index directory just keeps growing. It started with _0 files, then _1 files appeared, then _2 and _3 files. I am passing in false to the IndexWriter's constructor for the 'create' parameter, if there are existing files in that directory when it begins:

```
indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, analyzer, (azureDirectory.ListAll().Length == 0), IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
if (indexWriter != null)
{
    // Set the number of segments to save in memory before writing to disk.
    indexWriter.MergeFactor = 1000;
    indexWriter.UseCompoundFile = false;
    indexWriter.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(800);
        ...
    indexWriter.Dispose(); indexWriter = null;
}
```

Maybe it's realated to the UseCompoundFile flag?

Every couple of minutes, I create a new IndexWriter, process 10,000 documents, then dispose the IndexWriter. The index works, but the growing number of files is very bad, because I'm using AzureDirectory which copies every file out of Azure into a cache directory before starting the Lucene write.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behavior. If you want a single index segment you have some options:

- Use compound files
- Use a MergeFactor of 1 if you use `LogMergePolicy`, which is the default policy for lucene 3.0. Note that the method you use on the `IndexWriter` is just a convenience method that calls mergePolicy.MergeFactor as long as mergePolicy is an instance of `LogMergePolicy`.
- Run an optimization after each updates to your index

Low merge factors and optimizations after each updates can have serious drawbacks on the performance of your app which will depend on the type of indexing you do.

See this link which documents a little bit the effects of `MergeFactor` : 
http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/LogMergePolicy.html#setMergeFactor%28%29

Comment: I thought I had read that the optimization was not a smart thing to do when using AzureDirectory. Do you have any experience with that? Also, why use a MergeFactor of 1? I thought that a large factor would reduce writes to the files so speed up the document additions. Thanks--it's good to clarify the conflicting information available online.

Comment: I have no experience with the AzureDirectory specific stuff, so I cannot tell you why it would be bad on Azure. With a large merge factor you will merge less often (at the cost of RAM usage), so indexing will be faster but searching will be slower. The MergeFactor also control the total number of segments allowed in the Index, this is not very well documented. The only mention I could find in the official doc is here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/LogMergePolicy.html#getMergeFactor%28%29